# How to handle exceptions in @bot.tree.command()?

Tags: python, error-handling, discord, discord.py, bots

**Goal:**

Send a custom message to the user as an interaction response when an error occurs while running the slash command notifying them of the error and why it may have happened.

**Current status:**

I used to use text commands for my bots, so the error handling was simple as listening for the `on_command_error()` event and sending a context.reply to the text command as so:

```
@bot.event
async def on_command_error(ctx,error):
  if isinstance(error, discord.ext.commands.errors.MissingPermissions):
        await ctx.reply("You don't have the perms to do that.")
```

This same event didn't work for the slash commands I made.

The slash commands themselves work as intended.

Here's a barebones example of what I'm doing as a command:

```
@bot.tree.command(name="test_command")
async def test(interaction: discord.Interaction):
    await interaction.response.defer(ephemeral=True)
    await asyncio.sleep(5)
    await interaction.followup.send("Command works.")
```

But in the case of, for example if the response fails without getting deferred, the command simply fails and the Console shows a 404 error.

**Purpose of question:**

I want a way to do **Goal** globally. How do I modify `on_command_error()` in a way that will work with slash commands or is there a separate handler for slash command exceptions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can register the error handler for the command tree by using the `bot.tree.error` decorator to register a coroutine to be the error handler, like with the `on_command_error` but with `discord.Interaction` instead of `discord.ext.commands.Context`. Demo:

```py
@bot.tree.error
async def on_app_command_error(interaction: discord.Interaction, error):
    # handle the errors here
    ...
```